# Why is not blocking read() interrupted after receiving SIGINT?

Tags: c, linux, signals

having this code:

```
   #include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BSIZE 16

static void sigalarm_handler(int signo)
{
    //cause SIGINT by returning
    return;
}

int main()
{
    sigset_t sigset;
    ssize_t nbytes;
    char buf[BSIZE];
     struct sigaction action;

    //initialize sigset and signal handler
    sigemptyset(&sigset);
    sigaddset(&sigset, SIGALRM);
     memset(&action, 0, sizeof(action));
     action.sa_handler = sigalarm_handler;
     sigaction(SIGALRM, &action, NULL);

    //infinite loop
    while (1)
    {
        alarm(2);
        printf("enter some input (3 chars)\n");

        sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &sigset, NULL);
        //should SIGALRM should interupt read after 2 secs
        nbytes = read(fileno(stdin), buf, 3);
        sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, NULL);

        if (nbytes < 0)
        {
            if (errno == EINTR)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        buf[3] = '\0';

        //sleep should get SIGALRM, which in turn calls sigalarm_handler which generates SIGINT and interupts sleep, but the SIGALRM shouldn't be wasted, because it is prolong until it is unblock and thus next loop should break out
        sleep(2);
        printf("you wrote: %s\n", buf);
    }
}
```

I would expect to interupt `read()` after 2 secs. But the read blocks indeterminately. How's that? shouldn't `SIGINT` interrupt the read()?

Comment: `if (retptr == NULL)` that is Undefined Behaviour as `retptr` is never initialised or set.

Comment: `retptr` cannot be `NULL`it's an array now.

Comment: Why do you have that `retptr` at all? Just remove that entire check.

Comment: `retptr` [aside from being unitialized] doesn't help you with the error return from `read`. You want: `ssize_t retval = read(...);` Then, you want: `if (retval < 0) { if (errno == EINTR) break;` Note that `errno` is _not_ set if a syscall/function does _not_ generate an error, so the value in `errno` may be from an unrelated function. You must check the return value (e.g. `retval`) _before_ looking at `errno`. `read` _does_ return `EINTR` and does so even with `signal` [vs. `sigaction`]

Comment: Given that you're reading `stdin`, you _may_ be tripping over the linux _kernel's_ TTY driver in _canonical_ mode. To do true byte-at-a-time processing, you may need to set the driver into _raw_ mode. If so, see `man termios`

Comment: In fact, because you do `sigprocmask` _after_ the `read`, the `errno` value may be from the 2nd `sigprocmask` rather than the `read`. So, additionally, immediately after the `read`, you want: `int saverr = errno;`. And, check `saverr` instead of `errno` if `retval < 0`

Answer (score 0):

`signal()` is not perfectly clear about whether a system call is interrupted or automatically restarted; it may vary from one platform to another.
See the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html#NOTES), in the "NOTES/Portability" section at the end; it is stated that on Linux `signal()` uses the BSD semantics, which is equivalent to using `SA_RESTART` in `sigaction()` for *certain* system-calls (see [this page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) in the "Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers" section).

`sigaction()` offers a better control.

You may replace `signal(SIGALRM, sigalarm_handler);` by

```
struct sigaction action;
memset(&action, 0, sizeof(action));
action.sa_handler=sigalarm_handler;
sigaction(SIGALRM, &action, NULL);
```

Putting a `printf()` right after the call to `read()` shows that this call is interrupted when using `sigaction()` but not when using `signal()` (at least on my system).

As stated in the comments of the question, the fact that the loop does not stop is essentially due to clumsiness in the algorithm: various attempts of `if` with uninitialised or irrelevant variables (the code in the question was changed several times, now with `nbytes` it's OK), testing the *wrong* `errno`...

Here is an example trying to make explicit the situation after `read()`.

```
sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &sigset, NULL);
nbytes = read(fileno(stdin), buf, 3);
int read_errno=errno; // save errno because the next call to
                      // sigprogmask() could overwrite it
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, NULL);
if(nbytes==0)
{
  printf("EOF reached (Control-d for example)\n");
  break;
}
if(nbytes<0) // read() failed
{
  if(read_errno==EINTR)
  {
    printf("interrupted by a signal while reading\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("something really bad happened: %s\n",
           strerror(read_errno));
  }
  break;
}
printf("%d bytes were read\n", (int)nbytes); // read() succeeded
buf[nbytes] = '\0';
printf("you wrote: <%s>\n", buf);
```

Comment: even with `sigaction` the read is not interrupted (still loops). I would expect, the after `sleep(3)` (before printf), the alarm generates the SIGALRM and next loop breaks out, but it never breaks out.

Comment: @milanHrabos did you put a `printf()` with a `\n` just after the `read()` call?